# Athena/Presto: Getting maximum partition value, at cheapest scan cost

Tags: amazon-athena, presto

I am wanting to get the maximum value from a partition of my Athena table.
Given that the volume of scanned data is cost, am seeking a way to do this with minimum scan.

Admittedly, I have little data in there now but will grow over time once in production.

Does anyone know about what happens under the hood for these 2 approaches, how they differ, and which would be the most efficient?

Thanks

**Method (1)**

```
SELECT max(dt) 
FROM mydb.mytable
```

> -- Console Output:
> -- Time in queue:0.166 sec  Run time:3.153 sec  Data scanned:-

**Method (2)**

```
SELECT max(dt) 
FROM mydb."mytable$partitions"
```

> -- Console Output:
> -- Time in queue:0.223 sec  Run time:1.347 sec  Data scanned:0.02 KB

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Very very very late answer, but this question helped me a lot so I look it up, maybe it can help others:

```
SHOW PARTITIONS lists the partitions in metadata.
```

If you want to execute a SHOW PARTITIONS on a query you use:

```
SELECT * FROM "table_name$partitions"
```

The second example you posted it's faster because it doesn't look into the filesystem (S3) but only into the metadata.

AWS Documentation: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/show-partitions.html